# Push event and window.open, open only one window

Tags: javascript, postmessage, push-api

I have a website with a serviceWorker push event, and then a postMessage which sends back data. When this data is received, I open a window using `window.open`, but if I have like 3 tabs opened, the window is opened 3 times.

I put a specific name in window.open, I even tried setting a cookie just before `window.open`, and then when the cookie value is 1, `window.open` should not be triggered.

However it does not work, I guess because `window.open` is called for each tab at the same time so the cookie does not exists, and technically the window name does not exist either.

I'm stuck, if anyone has an idea...
Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried using `BroadcastChannel`, the Tab you want to listen to messages could then be the only one that subscribes to this Channel.     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API